# Fallo al abrir cualquier código en IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

yo tengo un problema con IntelliJ. Resulta que yo tenia una versión antigua del programa y lo he podido utilizar siempre sin ningún problema. Hoy me he decidido a actualizarlo porque habían añadido funcionalidades nuevas. El problema está en que ahora con la nueva versión me sale todo el código de cualquier programa con errores y no me deja ejecutar el código (adjunto foto).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Concretamente, los errores que me salen son como este: **Cannot resolve symbol 'Scanner'**.

Entonces, realizo esta pregunta porque no se de donde proviene el fallo. Lo único que se, es que se ha producido al actualizar la versión de IntelliJ. Yo estoy aprendiendo a programar en Java y no se muy bien lo que ocurre, pero lo que puedo apreciar es que los errores los da con las palabras "reservadas" de Java o con algún tipo de clases de Java.

Entonces, yo, sin tener mucho criterio se me puede ocurrir que el fallo pueda ser del java se / jdk que tenga instalado. Si se os ocurre algo, agradecería que me contestaseis. Y si sabeis como se puede ver en que path (directorio) está instalado el java jdk, y donde se configura el path del jdk en intelliJ os agradecería que también me lo dijeseis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si antes funcionaba pero después de actualizar el IDE no, no creo que sea un problema con el JDK.

Lo único que se me ocurre es que no tienes puesto el JDK correctamente. Puedes verlo en **File > Project Structure > Project SDK**.

Comment: En mi caso al abrir esta ventana me sale "JDK Home Path: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1\jbr" y en classpath no tengo ninguna ruta. No se si tendría que cambiar la ruta del jdk home path por la que esta instalado el jdk: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291 . Te paso de todas formas una captura de como tengo esa ventana : https://imgur.com/a/59ZtrpY (Enlace en el que esta la captura). No se si cambiando lo de jdk home path lo configuramos correctamente o hace falta hacer algo más... Si sabe algo me comenta.

Comment: Vale, ya lo he probado. Solamente he cambiado el directorio de JDK Home Path por el directorio donde ya tengo instalado el jdk y ya me ha funcionado. Gracias.

Comment: Recuerda calificar la respuesta correcta por si algún otro usuario tiene el mismo problema no tenga que crear nuevamente la pregunta